EntityFramework .net 6 getting object that are in provided list
I have list of objects used as filter:
public class Filter {
public int id {get; set;};
public DateTime myDate {get; set};
}

List<Filter> filters ...

I have a repository and I want to query like:
var result = context.MyObjects.Where(o =>  filters.Contains(new Filter (){id = o.id, myDate = o.myDate});

But it doesnt work, it complains that it cant be converted to sql query, probably because Contains uses complex object (Filter) and not int or guid.
Is there any way to fix it? How can I perform query like this? Basically I need to do inner join on sql table with my in memory Filter list.
